# сдвиг элементов строки на javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var st="ABCD--W-";
var st1="ANGH---";


document.write(st);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(st1);
```

как осуществить сдвиг в строке? при первом нахождении знака минус "-", он перемещался всегда перед буквой "А"

Comment: Что значит "сдвиг", "перемещался"? Покажите исходную строку и ту, которая должна получиться в итоге.

Comment: Исходные строки:
st="ABCD--W-";
var st1="ANGH---";
Строки, которые должны получиться:
st="-ABCD-W-";
st1="-ANGH--";

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
function move(s) {
    var searchIndex = s.search(/[^-]-/);
    if (-1 !== searchIndex) {
        s = '-' + s.slice(0, searchIndex + 1) + s.slice(searchIndex + 2);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
var st1 = 'ABCD--W-';
var st2 = 'ANGH---';
var st3 = 'ABC-D';

console.log(move(st1));
console.log(move(st2));
console.log(move(st3));
```